# Tyrus: silent server start failure

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, grizzly, tyrus

We are currently trying to implement WebSocket server using [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) and everything went alright (server-client communication worked well) until we tried to test what happens if server initialization fails (e.g. bad port).

The underlying code throws SocketException (permission denied). The exception is written to stdout but the server proceeds and the program continues beyond start() method.

```
public void runServer() {
    // bad port number
    Server server = new Server("localhost", 10, "/websockets", null, EchoEndpoint.class);

    try {
        server.start();
        // this line should not be printed
        System.out.println("Server started");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Please press a key to stop the server.");
        reader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to detect whether the server started successfully?

EDIT: We know we cannot use port 10 (that is why we tried it). We just need to check whether the server is running (by somehow catching the exception). (And we do not want to test it by an attempt to send some dummy data with a client - that would not really fix the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your port number '10' is too low to be used by regular user. You must be privileged user or use a port number greater than 1024:

```
Server server = new Server("localhost", 1025, "/websockets", null, EchoEndpoint.class)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know that this port cannot be used. That is why the server does not start (and it is the easiest way to "simulate" failed start). My question was how to detect that the server did not start.